# HTML paragraph width not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem: I have set the width of a paragraph, but it doesn't seem to have applied.

```
<p style="">
    <center><img src="img/Arraying.png"></center>
</p>

<p style="max-width:500px;"><font size="+2"><center><b>Arraying: Web & Java Developer.</b></font>
    <br>
    <i>Hey, I'm Arraying. I'm the web and Java developer for Minevelop. My specialities are small, yet complex Spigot plugins, web development, and plugin configuration.
                        <br><br>I've been server managing since I was eleven or twelve, and over the years I have gained a lot of experiences.
                        <br><br>Spigot: https://www.spigotmc.org/members/_wiildanimal_.81436/ 
                        <br>Enjin: http://www.enjin.com/profile/9844615
                        <br>Email: arraying@minevelop.com</i>
    </center>
</p>

<p style="">
    <br>
    <br>
    <center><img src="img/DomThePotato.png"></center>
</p>

<p style="max-width:500px;"><font size="+2"><center><b>DomThePotato: Lead Java Developer.</b></font>
    <br>
    <i>Hello, my name is Dom, aka DomThePotato, and I am the lead Java developer here at Minevelop. I specialise in utility plugins and everything that is not minigames. With over 1 and a half years of experience, I will be able to get any request done! Also experienced file configurer and backend administrator.
                        <br><br>Spigot: https://www.spigotmc.org/members/domthepotat.38275/
                        <br>Enjin: http://www.enjin.com/profile/7005362
                        <br>Email: domthepotato@minevelop.com</i>
    </center>
</p>
```

The first paragraph about Arraying seems to work fine, yet the one about Dom just doesn't want to be 500px wide.

I'm really tired, so if the error is completely stupid please forgive me.

Comment: Next time, please include the code right in the question.

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: @Paulie_D `<center>` is obsolete! https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features

Comment: Isn't that what I said? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center  BTW,,,so is `<font>`!

Comment: @Paulie_D No, you said deprecated. Not the same thing. Deprecated is a warning that it will be obsoleted some time in the future. The MDN article needs to be updated to what the spec says.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `max-width` I think you need to just use `width`:

```
<p style="width: 500px;"> HTML </p>
```

Comment: I just looked at your website www.minevelop.com, and it appears that the `p` tag closes right after the `font` tag, then the center tag contains everything. Make sure your code has all the matching end tags.

Comment: You can set the `width` of the center like so and you will see what I mean:
`<center style="width:500px;"> HTML </center>`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand; what section is this in? Both of them?

Comment: The explanation is quite complicated, the short of it is: the `p` tag has some very strange behavior and should not be used to contain other elements. I highly suggest you use divs as containers instead of the `p` tag. (i.e.) `<div style="width:500px;><center>...</center></div>` etc.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. I've fixed it with <center style>, thank you for your help. Are there any alternatives to using p's, that aren't divs?

Comment: @Arraying the closest thing to a `p` tag that has more natural behavior is the `span` tag, it is pretty much halfway between a `p` and a `div`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way your html is structured. Both

tag and  tags are inline elements. If you want to make all of the elemnts withing the

tag stay in a max-width container, then you should try changing the

tag to a  tag.

Your code would look like this:

```
<div style="max-width:500px;"><font size="+2"><center><b>DomThePotato: Lead Java Developer.</b></font>
<br>
<i>Hello, my name is Dom, aka DomThePotato, and I am the lead Java developer here at Minevelop. I specialise in utility plugins and everything that is not minigames. With over 1 and a half years of experience, I will be able to get any request done! Also experienced file configurer and backend administrator.
                    <br><br>Spigot: https://www.spigotmc.org/members/domthepotat.38275/
                    <br>Enjin: http://www.enjin.com/profile/7005362
                    <br>Email: domthepotato@minevelop.com</i>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Hans Strausl mentioned, your HTML tags aren't nested properly (I believe you want the `<center>` tag to wrap the `<font>` tag, but you can always reverse them again if I've misinterpreted).  Also, changing the `<p>` tags to `<div>`s seemed to achieve what you're looking for.

Here's a fiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/wzazrn5p/